# Magento : "index" append to email template url

Tags: magento, email-templates

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

In email templates facing one issue.

When I use
`<a style="" href="{{store url=''}}">`

it give me o/p like

`<a style="" href="http://www.domain.com/index.php">`

But I want like following

`<a style="" href="http://www.domain.com">`

Now If I add

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='service'}}">
```

It give me o/p like

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.php/service">
```

But I want like following

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/service">
```

Now If I add

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='service/contact'}}">
```

It give me o/p like (/index/index automatically appended)

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.php/service/contact/index/index">
```

But I want like following

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/service/contact">
```

And when I click on link it will navigate me to /service page not service/contact page.

Any idea what's this going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following has done the job.

```
{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}

<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}service"
```